# Probability calibration is worsening my model performance

Tags: machine-learning, classification, probability-calibration

I'm using **RandomForest** and **XGBoost** for binary classification, and my task is to predict probabilities for each class. Since tree-based models are bad with outputting usable probabilities, i imported the `sklearn.calibration CalibratedClassifierCV`, trained RF on 40k, then trained CCV with a separate 10k samples ( with `cv="prefit"` option ), my metric ( Area Under ROC ) is showing a huge drop in performance. Is it normal for probability calibration to alter the base estimator's behavior?

Edit : Since i'm minimizing logloss on my XGBClassifier, the output probabilities aren't that bad compared to RF's outputs.

Comment: Are you reporting a drop in AUC on a third test set, going from the base RF model to the CalibratedClassifier?

Comment: actually, the performance got worse for the dataset that i used for calibration.

Comment: But still the drop is from the score of the RF on that calibration set? If so, are you able to share the (or a simplified) example? If not, then maybe it's just that the RF overfit the train set / the calibration set is not from the same distribution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The probability calibration is just stacking a logistic or isotonic regression on top of the base classifier.  The default is logistic, and since the sigmoid is a strictly increasing function, the rank-ordering of samples will be unaffected, and so AUC should not change at all.

(With isotonic regression, it's actually piecewise-constant, so within a span where the function is constant, all samples will have their scores made equal, and so your ROC curve will become more coarse, which would affect the AUC; but these effects ought to be small, as long as the isotonic fit produces sufficiently many/short constant segments.)

Also, gradient boosting like XGBoost produces scores biased *toward* the extremes, not away from them like random forests, so the logistic calibration is unlikely to work out well.

Comment: if not logistic calibration on tree-based models, then isotonic should be fine? or should i look for something else?

Comment: It's specifically gradient boosted trees, not all tree models, where logistic/ sigmoid/Platt is ill-suited. Check a calibration plot; the GBM probably won't look sigmoidal. Isotonic should be fine, but check calibration afterward.

Comment: btw, i'm using logistic loss as objective in my xgboost model, i checked the probabilities output by predict_proba, and i think i can sacrify the discrepancies of the probabilities which are not that static ,to be honest,to keep a good classification score on my metric.